# Manipulating by groups within data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, data-manipulation

I have a data frame that looks more or less like this (but much longer and with more ObsDOY values):

```
   Position              ObsDOY Offset Lin_Flux
   <chr>                  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Inter-row (unplanted)    122      1    10.7 
 2 Tree row                 122      1    10.3 
 3 Tree row                 122      1    16.2 
 4 Inter-row (planted)      122      1     9.08
 5 Inter-row (trenched)     122      1     3.57
 6 Inter-row (trenched)     122      1    12.3 
 7 Inter-row (trenched)     122      1     9.36
 8 Inter-row (trenched)     122      1     7.73
 9 Inter-row (trenched)     122      1    10.1 
10 Inter-row (trenched)     122      1     7.14
11 Inter-row (planted)      143      1     4.44
```

I want to add a new column that is the difference between the `Lin_Flux` of each position and the average of the `Lin_flux` values that correspond with `Position = "Inter-row (trenched)"` and have the same `ObsDOY` (Observation Day of Year). In other words:

`newcol <- Lin_flux[ObsDOY=x] - mean(Lin_flux[ObsDOY=x AND Position = "Inter-row (trenched)"])`

I would know how to achieve this manually using the `dplyr` package to filter out subsets and then work with those, but I would very much appreciate advice on a more elegant solution, since I will be continuously adding more observations and do not want to have to rewrite the script to include new `ObsDOY` values every time.

Comment: Could you please include a manually worked out example of your expected output and paste a copy of your sample data from the output of  `dput(your_dataframe)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` without needing to manually subset each different `ObsDOY` value. To do it, you create a new dataset of `Lin_Flux` means for each value of `ObsDOY` after filtering out only those observations where `Position == "Inter-row (trenched)"`.

After that, you merge the data back to the original dataset and take the difference.

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- tribble(
~ID, ~Position,              ~ObsDOY, ~Offset, ~Lin_Flux,
1, "Inter-row (unplanted)",    122,      1,    10.7, 
2, "Tree row",                 122,      1,    10.3, 
3, "Tree row",                 122,      1,    16.2, 
4, "Inter-row (planted)",      122,      1,     9.08,
5, "Inter-row (trenched)",     122,      1,     3.57,
6, "Inter-row (trenched)",     122,      1,    12.3, 
7, "Inter-row (trenched)",     122,      1,     9.36,
8, "Inter-row (trenched)",     122,      1,     7.73,
9, "Inter-row (trenched)",     122,      1,    10.1, 
10, "Inter-row (trenched)",     122,      1,     7.14,
11, "Inter-row (planted)",      143,      1,     4.44
)

df %>%
    filter(Position == "Inter-row (trenched)") %>%
    group_by(ObsDOY) %>%
    summarize(Lin_Flux_mean = mean(Lin_Flux)) %>%
    right_join(df, by = c("ObsDOY")) %>%
    mutate(Lin_Flux_diff = Lin_Flux - Lin_Flux_mean)

# A tibble: 11 x 7
   ObsDOY Lin_Flux_mean    ID Position              Offset Lin_Flux Lin_Flux_diff
    <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>
 1    122          8.37     1 Inter-row (unplanted)      1    10.7          2.33 
 2    122          8.37     2 Tree row                   1    10.3          1.93 
 3    122          8.37     3 Tree row                   1    16.2          7.83 
 4    122          8.37     4 Inter-row (planted)        1     9.08         0.713
 5    122          8.37     5 Inter-row (trenched)       1     3.57        -4.80 
 6    122          8.37     6 Inter-row (trenched)       1    12.3          3.93 
 7    122          8.37     7 Inter-row (trenched)       1     9.36         0.993
 8    122          8.37     8 Inter-row (trenched)       1     7.73        -0.637
 9    122          8.37     9 Inter-row (trenched)       1    10.1          1.73 
10    122          8.37    10 Inter-row (trenched)       1     7.14        -1.23 
11    143         NA       11 Inter-row (planted)        1     4.44        NA
```

Comment: Thanks! I get back "Error: Join columns must be present in data.
x Problem with `ObsDOY`.". Not sure where I went wrong exactly. Sorry if I can't be more specific, I'm aware it could be one of a thousand issues with the rest of my script

Comment: The error means that there isn't a column named "ObsDOY" in the data. The most likely culprits are different punctuation (e.g., Obs_DOY) or different capitalization (e.g., OBS_DOY). If you can edit the question to paste your data, like @Peter suggested, and paste your code, that would help to figure out what's going on.

Comment: After giving up yesterday I tried again this morning and it miraculously worked! Thank you very much for the help, next time I will try provide a better example

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice (as I also had to learn) to include some example data that makes it easier to reproduce your problem. I took the liberty of doing that based on what I understand you want to do.

If this is your data:

```
df <- data.frame(Position = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"), ObsDOY = c("Mon", "Mon", "Tue", "Tue", "Mon", "Fri", "Fri"), Lin_Flux = c(2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 1))
```

Then this would achieve your desired result.

```
df <- df %>% 
    group_by(Position, ObsDOY) %>% 
    mutate(newcol = Lin_Flux - mean(Lin_Flux))
```

You're on the right track with `dplyr` - `group_by` basically creates little subsamples based on the variables you specify, everything that follows then (such as using `mean()`) is then done on these subsamples.

Comment: Appreciate it. I will try do it this way next time.